# Isolate the THIRD octet from an IP address and put it in a variable. This line is doing the 4th. macOS/AppleScript/Automator using /bin/bash

Tags: applescript, ip-address, automator

Script:

```
read IP SIP < <(exec ifconfig en0 | awk '/inet / { t = $2; sub(/.*[.]/, "", t); print $2, t }')
```

I am trying to isolate the THIRD octet xxx.xxx.000.xxx and put it into a variable. Help? Thanks!

Comment: What **language** are you trying to do this in? Please update your question to add the relevant tag.

Comment: MacOS/Using Automator AppleScript

Answer (score 1):

The following will set the third octet to the `thirdOctet` *variable*:

```
set thirdOctet to do shell script "ifconfig en0 | awk -F . '/inet /{print $3}'"
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple AppleScript solution

```
set ipv4Address to do shell script "ifconfig en0 | awk '/inet / {print $2}'"
set {TID, text item delimiters} to {text item delimiters, "."}
set thirdOctet to text item 3 of ipv4Address
set text item delimiters to TID

display dialog thirdOctet buttons {"OK"} default button "OK"
```